# RRR use in a specific paper

Tags: regression, reduced-rank-regression

I am trying to understand how RRR has been used in a [paper](https://bmcmedicine.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12916-021-01958-x) in which the association between cardio vascular diseases and dietary patterns is investigated.

The paper says:

> The RRR analysis was used to identify dietary patterns
> that could explain the maximum variation in a set of nutrient response variables hypothesized to be on the
> causal pathway between predictors (food groups) and
> outcomes (CVD and all-cause mortality events).

As far as I understand RRR is a dimension reduction techinique that selects variables which are able to explain most variance of the dependent variable. So, I would imagine that RRR here is used to define which food characteristics should enter into the model.

But right after they say:

> We selected the following response variables which contribute
> to excess energy intake: energy density (kJ/g), SFA (%
> total energy), free sugars (% total energy), and fiber
> density (g/MJ) as there is evidence for their role in the
> development of CVD and mortality

which confuses me. Are these variable selected for their role or are they part of the output of RRR?

Also, they say:

> Respondents were assigned a z-score for each dietary
> pattern which quantified how much their reported dietary intake reflected each dietary pattern relative to other
> respondents in the study sample. The RRR model calculates dietary pattern z-scores for each respondent as a
> linear, weighted combination of all of their standardized
> food group intakes by using weights unique to each dietary pattern

which has me a bit lost.